# Extraer los datos de los 8 post con mas view (Consulta SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un blog y quiero extraer los 8 artículos con mas visitas pero desconozco la sentencia que debo utilizar para conseguir lo que deseo. Tengo una tabla llamada `post` que es donde guardo los datos de todos los artículos publicados en mi web y también tengo una tabla llamada `view` que contiene un campo llamado `view` que almacena la cantidad de visitas de cada post. La cantidad de view de cada post los muestro correctamente por pantalla en mi blog. Pero lo que yo quiero conseguir ahora una sentencia **SQL** para mostrar los 8 post con mas cantidad de view.

### Tabla post:

```
CREATE TABLE post(
id_post             int(250) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_post_user        int(250) NOT NULL,
title               varchar(200) NOT NULL,
description_post    varchar(250) NOT NULL,
category            varchar(50) NOT NULL,
miniatura           varchar(250) NOT NULL,
img_description     varchar(250),
entrada             text NOT NULL,
tags                varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`status`            varchar(50),
browser_post        varchar(200),
ip_post             varchar(200),
create_at_post      datetime,
CONSTRAINT fk_post_user FOREIGN KEY(id_post_user) REFERENCES users(id_user)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

### Tabla view:

```
CREATE TABLE `view`(
id_view             int(250) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_view_post        int(250) NOT NULL,
id_view_user        int(250),
view                int(250),
browser_view        varchar(200),
ip_view             varchar(200),
create_at_view      datetime,
CONSTRAINT fk_view_post FOREIGN KEY(id_view_post) REFERENCES post(id_post),
CONSTRAINT fk_view_user FOREIGN KEY(id_view_user) REFERENCES users(id_user)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, si necesitan saber mas por favor solo dejadmelo saber. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que tendrías que ordenar los registros de la vista por view (según veo el numero de visitas que ha recibido cada post).
Y limitar la búsqueda a los 8 primiros con un LIMIT 8.
Es decir usando este query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM view ORDER BY view LIMIT 8";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

La variable $mysqli se refiere a la que estés usando con tu base de datos, que supongo será MySQL.
**EDITO**
Cierto como indica Intruzo, para buscar los 8 mayores hay que ordenar endescendente (de mayor a menor) por tanto el query sería realmente

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM view ORDER BY view DESC LIMIT 8";
$mysqli->query($query);
```

Ahora si esta completa la respuesta.

Comment: CORRIJO:  ORDER BY biew DESC LIMIT 8